# Distinct count with distinct count as filter

Tags: powerbi, analytics

I have a problem which should be simple, but I cannot get the correct result.

[image: Please refer to this image as example]

As  a result, I need to get the count of Order numbers having one Product category only:

(Orders 1111 and 4444 should not be counted since they include both categories).

The real tables have more than two product categories.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thank you!

So far have tried just basic filtering, without success.

Answer (score 0):

To perform this calc, is necessary to create a logic to filter orders with one product category and orders with more than one.

You can use SUMMARIZE to create a logical temporary table.

```
SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Order Number])
```

After this, you will have a table which will be possible to filter the orders with one or more associations.

So, is basically necessary a filter operation using FILTER and ALLEXCEPT to deal with contexts.

```
FILTER(
    SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Order Number]),
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Product Category]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Order Number])
    ) = 1
```

Finally, with a filtered temporary table, it is possible to use CALCULATE with DISTINCTCOUNT to get the final results.

```
Order Count = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Order Number]),
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Order Number]),
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Product Category]),
            ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Order Number])
        ) = 1
    )
)
```

Here is the result, similar to you specified.

[image]

You need to keep in mind that logic is encapsulated, starting from the inside out.

To develop DAX codes like this, you can use Dax in New Tables into Power BI or use tool like Dax Studio, focused on more complex calculations.